# How to create a floating layer of signs that lets eggs through in a chicken coop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had previously been using signs as a layer to hold water in a chicken coop (the chickens float in the water and drop eggs through), and underneath the layer of signs I had another layer of water which sweeps all the eggs out to one end. However when I stacked my signs to build a coop today, they broke when I removed the layer underneath.

I think I can still walk under the chickens to collect the eggs by stacking 2 signs on top of each other in each square of the coop, but water can no longer flow underneath to sweep them out of the coop.

How can I make the signs float? Or is there something else I can use instead as a layer that holds water but lets eggs through?

Comment: ... I could have sworn signs always broke when the block they were attached to (either a wall or the ground) was removed.

Comment: @TrentHawkins, I think you're correct; I believe I just tried to build my coop in a different way to what I previously did, and thought it was caused by a version change. I'll reword my question so that it's still useful.

Comment: instead of using signs and water you can use hoppers to collect the eggs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place the signs against each other. Put the first one on a wall, then put the next one on the first one, and continue the process for all of them. I hope that helps.

**Edit:** As of 1.8, you need to shift click on signs to place them against each other.